# Call a variable in all controllers

Tags: php, symfony

the title of the application is not very clear .... I am looking to use a smarty variable that is calling in my main controller siteController.php. This variable is calling in my banner which is calling everywhere in the project except that of course being given that the variable is calling only in my controller that displays my home page, it will not work on the other page. the current code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->get('app.bdd')->parameterGetOrAdd('VERSION', '1') < 1.5 && $this->getUser()) 
      return $this->redirectToRoute('account_home');

    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rep_user   = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:User');
    $rep_message = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Message');
    $rep_region = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Region');
    $rep_notice = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Notice');
    $rep_presse = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Presse');
    $rep_publicitaire = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Publicitaire');
    $slide = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Slide');

    $session = $request->getSession();
    $aviva_displayed = $session->get('aviva_displayed', 0);
    if ($aviva_displayed == 0)
    {
        $session->set('aviva_displayed', 1);
    }



    $day_captain = $rep_user->getCaptainOfTheDay();
    // $day_passengers = $rep_user->getPassengersOfCaptainOfTheDay($day_captain);
    $notices     = $rep_notice->getLastNoticesForCaptain($day_captain, 3);

    $regions     = $rep_region->findBy(array(), array('name'=>'ASC'));

    $presses     = $rep_presse->getForSite();

    $publicitaires_g = $rep_publicitaire->findBy(array('hook' => 'block_gauche'), array('id' => 'DESC'),1);
    $publicitaires_c = $rep_publicitaire->findBy(array('hook' => 'block_centre_bas'), array('id' => 'DESC'),1);

    $slide_show = $slide->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'), 5);

    foreach ($regions as $region)
    {
        $min_lat = (isset($min_lat)) ? min($region->getMinLatitude(), $min_lat)  : $region->getMinLatitude();
        $max_lat = (isset($max_lat)) ? max($region->getMaxLatitude(), $max_lat)  : $region->getMaxLatitude();
        $min_lng = (isset($min_lng)) ? min($region->getMinLongitude(), $min_lng) : $region->getMinLongitude();
        $max_lng = (isset($max_lng)) ? max($region->getMaxLongitude(), $max_lng) : $region->getMaxLongitude();
    }
    $map_area_km = max($this->get('app.bdd')->calculDistanceKm($min_lat, 0, $max_lat, 0)
                     , $this->get('app.bdd')->calculDistanceKm(0, $min_lng, 0, $max_lng));

    $main_map_elems = array(
        'area_km' => $map_area_km
        , 'center_lat' => ($min_lat + $max_lat) / 2
        , 'center_lng' => ($min_lng + $max_lng) / 2
    );

    // 12/04/2017 => plus d'Aviva
    $aviva_displayed = 1;

    // On récupére les messages de l'utilisateur connecté
    $users = $rep_user->getUserMessageWith($this->getUser());
    for ($ix=0, $messages=array(); $ix<sizeof($users); $ix++)
        $messages[] = $rep_message->getLastMessageOfDiscutionBeetween($users[$ix], $this->getUser());

    return $this->render('AppSiteBundle:Home:index.html.twig'
              , array('day_captain'=>$day_captain, 'main_map_elems'=>$main_map_elems
                    , 'notices'=>$notices, 'presses'=>$presses,
                    'messages_user' => $messages,
                    'publicitaires_g' => $publicitaires_g,
                    'publicitaires_c' => $publicitaires_c,
                    'slides' => $slide_show
                    , 'aviva_displayed'=>$aviva_displayed));
}
```

Template:

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">

                    <li><a class="mon-compte" href="{% if app.user is null %}{{ path('login_route') }}{% else %}{{ path('account_home') }}{% endif %}">{{ 'site.top_link.myaccount'|trans }}</a></li>

                    {% if app.user is null %}
                        {% if current_version >= 2 %}
                        <li><a class="devenir-passager" href="{{ path('subscribe_as_passenger') }}">{{ 'site.top_link.subscribe_passenger'|trans }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <li><a class="devenir-capitaine" href="{{ path('subscribe_as_captain') }}">{{ 'site.top_link.subscribe_captain'|trans }}</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="messages_show">
                            <a class="messages" href="{{ path('account_messages_list') }}">Mes messages
                            {% if service_bdd.messageCountNotViewed(app.user) > 0 %}
                                <span class="label red-clair rounded ">{{ service_bdd.messageCountNotViewed(app.user) }}</span>
                            {% endif %}
                            </a>
                            {{ app.user.getMessages }}
                            {#<p class="messages_hover">
                                {% for message in messages_user %}
                                    {% if loop.index % 2 == 0 %}{% set class = '' %}{% else %}{% set class= 'message-impair' %}{% endif %}
                                    {{ include("AppSiteBundle:Message:message_hover.html.twig", {"message": message, 'class': class}) }}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% if service_bdd.messageCountNotViewed(app.user) <= 0 %}
                                    <a>{{ 'Pas de nouveau message'|trans }}</a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>#}
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
```

the 2 templates are identical ...

Service:

```
public function getMessages()
{
    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rep_message = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:Message');
    $rep_user   = $em->getRepository('PublikaBDDBundle:User');

    // On récupére les messages de l'utilisateur connecté
    $users = $rep_user->getUserMessageWith($this->getUser());
    for ($ix=0, $messages=array(); $ix<sizeof($users); $ix++)
        $messages[] = $rep_message->getLastMessageOfDiscutionBeetween($users[$ix], $this->getUser());

    return array('messages_user' => $messages);
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the variable message_user

How can I display it everywhere? Thank you for your help

Comment: Typically you would use a [controller listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) for this sort of thing.

Comment: I can go through a service no?

Comment: I'm afraid there is too much of a language barrier for me to give you a useful response.  I can sort of see what you are trying to do with the code but the words?

Comment: I got the project from an old dev but the project was badly coded basic. I have to call the variable in 2 twig templates (I added it to my code).

Comment: You should look at global Twig variables: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I have to create my service like this (see posted code)

Comment: _I am trying to retrieve the variable message_user_ but the service defines `messages_user`, please check that your variables have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use render controller method : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

If this solution isn't correct, you can use session variable in your twig template : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/app_variable.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We tend to avoid answers with a lot of information in hyperlinks. Could you extract the useful information from these links, provide a working example, and some explanations as why this method is a good one ?